# Attempting to exectue SQL script but can't find how to connect it to my SQL Server CE database

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2012

I've generated my `edmx.sqlce` script using the generate from model approach within the Entity Framework but can't figure out how to execute the script against my database.

Note that the method needs to work with visual studio 11 Beta.

Could anyone let me know how I can connect it to the compact database file and then execute the sql script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox Visual Studio add-in for this (install via Extension Manager in Visual Studio 11)

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem and I've been searching for the soluting this entire day. I wonder why Microsoft would release a version of the database without an official tool to properly manage it.